# Не находится включенный Java-проект в композитной сборке Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Имеется два Gradle проекта - lib и project. Project зависит от lib (lib собирается в jar и паблишится в репозиторий). Цель - запускать project с подтянутым jar-ником lib, и при необходимости должна быть возможность собирать композитный gradle билд в среде IntelliJ IDEA.
Проблема - project успешно запускается с подтянутом jar-ником lib, однако композитный билд не работает - если jar нет, то IDE просто ругается что библиотека не найдена, хотя подключен проект lib. Известно, что IDEA умеет сама автоматически использовать включенный проект (не используя jar), даже без includeBuild '../projectName' в settings.gradle, НО даже если указывать это, то включенная сборка все равно не используется. В чем может быть проблема, что я упустил?

**Структура проекта lib:**

```
    lib_project_from_git
       -src
          -main
             -java
                - ru.testcompany.test.lib
                      - packageone
                      - packagetwo
                      - packagethree
             - resources
```

**Структура build.gradle lib проекта:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

version = "0.1"

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

def logbackVersion = "1.1.8"

dependencies {
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:${logbackVersion}"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}"

}


publishing {

    repositories {
        maven {
        name 'company'
        url "http://justUrl"
}
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
    }
}

publications {
    lib(MavenPublication) {
        ext.repo = 'company'
        artifactId 'lib'
        groupId 'ru.testcompany.test.lib'
        from components.java
        }
    }
 }

jar {
    baseName = 'lib'
    manifest {
        attributes("Version": version,
                "Build-By": System.getProperty("user.name"),
                "Build-Time-UTC": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"),
                "Built-JDK": System.getProperty("java.version"),
                "Built-Host": InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName(),
                "Source-Compatibility": project.sourceCompatibility,
                "Target-Compatibility": project.targetCompatibility)
    }
}
```

**Часть структуры build.gradle project проекта:**

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://justurl"
    }
    mavenLocal()
}

def logbackVersion = "1.1.7"
def junitVersion = "4.12"
def libVersion= "0.3"

dependencies {
    testCompile "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:${logbackVersion}"
    testCompile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}"
    testCompile "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
    testCompile "ru.testcompany.test:lib:${libVersion}"
}
```

**settings.gradle проекта project:**

```
rootProject.name = 'project_from_git'

// напрямую включать проект тоже не работает
// includeBuild '../lib_project_from_git'
```

Проект project_from_git в IDEA открыт как основной, проект lib_project_from_git подключается через "Atache Gradle Project" вкладки градл, а далее выставляется галочка у проекта project_from_git в меню "Composite Build Configuratuion" напротив проекта lib_project_from_git.

Версия IDEA - 2018.1

Версия Gralde - 3.5

Имеются подобные похожие проекты, и там композитный билд работает корректно.

P.S. Представленные названия проектов являются заменой реальных имен на более общие, по причине конфиденциальности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена добавлением следующего:

1. В *settings.gradle* lib проекта: `rootProject.name = 'lib'`
2. В *settings.gradle* project проекта: `rootProject.name = 'project'`
3. В *build.gralde* lib проекта: `group = 'ru.testcompany.test'`